# DCOS unable to install & run ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb, dcos

I have installed DCOS with one agent and 3 masters and tried installing ArangoDB but it is failing to deploy arangodb.

**Below is the config seen as per the log.**

> ArangoDB Image: arangodb/arangodb-mesos:3.0
>
> Mode: cluster
>
> Asynchronous replication flag: 0
>
> SecondariesWithDBservers: 0
>
> CoordinatorsWithDBservers: 0
>
> SecondarySameServer: 0
>
> ArangoDBForcePullImage: 1
>
> ArangoDBPrivilegedImage: 0
>
> Minimal resources agent: mem(*):2048;cpus(*):0.25;disk(*):2048
>
> Minimal resources DBserver: mem(*):4096;cpus(*):1;disk(*):4096
>
> Minimal resources secondary DBserver:
>   mem(*):4096;cpus(*):1;disk(*):4096
>
> Minimal resources coordinator: mem(*):4096;cpus(*):1;disk(*):1024
>
> Number of agents in agency: 3
>
> Number of DBservers: 2
>
> Number of coordinators: 2
>
> zookeeper: zk://master.mesos:2181/arangodb3

**And below is the error seen in the log file.**

> 0901 07:07:34.769537    23 CaretakerCluster.cpp:422] planned agent
>   instances: 3, running agent instances: 1
>
> I0901 07:07:34.769601    23 Caretaker.cpp:400] Declining offer
>   e2301ebe-fff0-46a5-b71b-ef77b9a7a764-O11
>
> I0901 07:07:37.474743    24 HttpServer.cpp:439] handling http request
>   'GET /v1/health.json'
>
> I0901 07:07:40.802276    23 CaretakerCluster.cpp:416] And here the
>   offer:
>
> {"id":{"value":"e2301ebe-fff0-46a5-b71b-ef77b9a7a764-O12"},"framework_id":{"value":"37ac79b8-bc37-4493-9558-aa72638290db-0002"},"slave_id":{"value":"37ac79b8-bc37-4493-9558-aa72638290db-S0"},"hostname":"192.168.12.167","url":{"scheme":"http","address":{"hostname":"192.168.12.167","ip":"192.168.12.167","port":5051},"path":"/slave(1)","query":[]},"resources":[{"name":"ports","type":1,"ranges":{"range":[{"begin":1026,"end":2180},{"begin":2182,"end":3887},{"begin":3889,"end":5049},{"begin":5052,"end":8079},{"begin":8082,"end":8180},{"begin":8182,"end":17140},{"begin":17144,"end":32000}]},"role":"*"},{"name":"disk","type":0,"scalar":{"value":1.17866e+06},"role":"*"},{"name":"cpus","type":0,"scalar":{"value":7.5},"role":"*"},{"name":"mem","type":0,"scalar":{"value":12298},"role":"*"}],"attributes":[],"executor_ids":[]}
>
> I0901 07:07:40.802320    23 CaretakerCluster.cpp:422] planned agent
>   instances: 3, running agent instances: 1
>
> I0901 07:07:40.802383    23 Caretaker.cpp:400] Declining offer
>   e2301ebe-fff0-46a5-b71b-ef77b9a7a764-O12

I believe one agent server is also sufficient. Is it that number of the agents should also be 3 servers ?

Also need to know how to restart the entire cluster and single service if need be ? (Killing processes doesn't seem to be right way)

Can someone suggest what exactly needs to done here...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that you only have one Agent node (which would explain only one instance running)? ArangoDB needs at least 3 agent nodes.
See the pre-install note: https://github.com/mesosphere/universe/blob/version-3.x/repo/packages/A/arangodb3/4/package.json#L10

Comment: The ArangoDB framework will insist on putting your 2 DBServers on different Mesos-Agents. If you really have only one Mesos-Agent, then ArangoDB cannot be deployed with the parameters you gave.

Comment: @js84 - Thought so! There is only one agent node by DCOS is trying to install 3 agents on same servers. DCOS installation went through with 3 masters and one agent.

Comment: There is some misunderstanding here. Both ArangoDB and DC/OS use the term "Agent". ArangoDB will start tasks on DC/OS agents. The most basic task that ArangoDB needs is its own agency consisting of 1:n (ArangoDB)-Agents. The default configuration will try to launch 3 (ArangoDB)-Agents. Each of these has to run on a different (DC/OS) Agent. Otherwise the setup would not be resilient. Either add more DC/OS agents (then the arangodb agency should come up) or change the arangodb dcos configuration so that it only starts 1 agent, 1 coordinator and 1 dbserver

Comment: @mop - Thanks for the information! I added 2 more agents and now it worked fine!